# How do I center text over a background image without moving the image underneath? HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, image, margin, centering

I have an image that is under the background image property and I have some lines of text within that div class. I keep using the margin top property to move the text to center it over the image but it also adds a margin to the image. I tried to use the padding prop but it also stretches the background I put on. How do I center this text without it adding that margin to the image underneath it? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Pleas show us some code and what you have tried.

Comment: Show your codes to make it much more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You can center text using `text-align: center`, `margin: auto`. Also, using `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;`. If element has absolute positioning it entails another solution. Perhaps, you should align your div, but... Need to clarify with code example for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

In css file